# How to get the driver letter from dbcc name in Windows?

Tags: winapi, usb

I want to detect USB disk insertion in a Windows Service. And I use RegisterDeviceNotification  function. IN DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE, I can get dbcc name. 
My question is: How can I know which driver is inserted according to the dbcc name?

Thanks.